# Is it possible to use the frontend-maven-plugin for starting web application in development mode (vuejs+springboot)?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, maven, vue.js

I have used this blog:

https://jaxlondon.com/blog/java-core-languages/put-spring-boot-und-vue-js-practical-use-project-tutorial/

to create a maven project that contains both my **frontend** and **backend** and everything is working as expected.

I have some doubts on how to run the application in *development* mode though. Currently I have:

**frontend/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
...
```

**frontend/vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // proxy all webpack dev-server requests starting with /api
  // to our Spring Boot backend (localhost:8088) using http-proxy-middleware
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8098', // this configuration needs to correspond to the Spring Boot backends' application.properties server.port
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },
  // Change build paths to make them Maven compatible
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/
  outputDir: 'target/dist',
  assetsDir: 'static'
};
```

**frontend/pom.xml**

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${frontend-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <!-- See versions of node here: https://nodejs.org/dist/  -->
              <nodeVersion>v10.0.0</nodeVersion>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>npm run build</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <arguments>run serve</arguments>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

To start my application in development mode I have tried to just replace:

```
        <configuration>
          <arguments>run build</arguments>
        </configuration>
```

with:

```
        <configuration>
          <arguments>run serve</arguments>
        </configuration>
```

When I build my application it starts the development server:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.8.0:npm (npm run build) @ frontend ---
[INFO] Running 'npm run serve' in /home/user/repos/webapp/frontend
[INFO] 
[INFO] > frontend@1.0.0 serve /home/user/repos/webapp/frontend
[INFO] > vue-cli-service serve
[INFO] 
[INFO]  INFO  Starting development server...
[INFO]  98% after emitting CopyPlugin DONE  Compiled successfully in 1241ms11:07:40            
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO]   App running at:
[INFO]   - Local:   http://localhost:8081/ 
[INFO]   - Network: http://192.168.0.23:8081/
[INFO] 
[INFO]   Note that the development build is not optimized.
[INFO]   To create a production build, run npm run build.
```

But when I modify and save e.g. **src/App.vue** I get:

```
[INFO]  WAIT  Compiling...11:10:29
[INFO] 
[INFO]  98% after emitting CopyPlugin WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings11:10:30           
[INFO] 
[INFO]  warning  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js
[INFO] 
[INFO] "export 'default' (imported as 'mod') was not found in '-!../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js'
```

and I just have a blank page in my browser.

I did not find any documentation on how to configure the **frontend-maven-plugin** for starting in development mode so maybe I am not going to have success with this. But I do like that I can version node/npm from **frontend-maven-plugin** and use the exact same version of node/npm both for my build and my development.

Of course I can install node/npm on my linux box (and make sure to use the same version as I specify in the **frontend-maven-plugin**) and then run my application in development mode *outside* of maven but that seems like a rather broken workflow - I want my full development and build/deployment process to use the same version of node/npm and ideally be configured in one place (in maven).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use basically the same setup as described in that blog post for almost 3 years now. IMHO you misunderstood the purpose of frontend-maven-plugin. AFAIK it's supposed to build your JS application in Maven process before packaging. It's not to ease development of JS application / switch between NodeJS versions on your machine. This is also what I understand from their README: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

> What is this plugin meant to do?
>
> - Let you keep your frontend and
>   backend builds as separate as possible, by reducing the amount of
>   interaction between them to the bare minimum; using only 1 plugin.
> - Let
>   you use Node.js and its libraries in your build process without
>   installing Node/NPM globally for your build system
> - Let you ensure that
>   the version of Node and NPM being run is the same in every build
>   environment
>
> What is this plugin not meant to do?
>
> - Not meant to replace
>   the developer version of Node - frontend developers will still install
>   Node on their laptops, but backend developers can run a clean build
>   without even installing Node on their computer.
> - Not meant to install
>   Node for production uses. The Node usage is intended as part of a
>   frontend build, running common javascript tasks such as minification,
>   obfuscation, compression, packaging, testing etc.

This plugin makes it really easy to switch NodeJS versions for building purposes. For development / production IMHO it's much better to use NVM to manage NodeJS versions:

- https://michael-kuehnel.de/node.js/2015/09/08/using-vm-to-switch-node-versions.html

And to run "npm run serve" I simply run it in command line.

Comment: Yes I read that as well but was wondering if there was an "easy" way to tweak it into supporting dev mode as well. So in your case I assume you specify node version in two different places. In pom.xml for build/PROD and somewhere else for DEV? And then of course cross your fingers that those two values never get out of sync? :-)

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible (to use it for supporting dev mode). Yes, in pom.xml I have NodeJS version for prod. And with NVM I specify version for dev. I don't change NodeJS version very often (only if something stops working), but when I do, I change it in both places. You are right that it means that I can get to a situation where for development I would use some version and for production build I would use another version, but so far even though this already happened, everything worked just fine.